# L = { a^n b^n c^m d^m : n >= 1, m >= 1 } U { a^n b^m c^m d^n : n >= 1, m >= 1 } isRegular?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata, context-free-language, pumping-lemma

there is a lot of examples for pumpinglemma proof, but I did not figure out this, can anyone help ?

L= { a^n b^n c^m d^m : n >= 1, m >= 1 } U { a^n b^m c^m d^n : n >= 1, m >= 1 }

Comment: None of these words can be generated using regular grammar rules. It would require some kind of memory, so at least pushdown automaton. Are you sure it isn't context-free language?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the regular language `R = a*b*cd`. The intersection of two regular languages must be a regular language. The intersection of `L` and `R` is `a^n b^n cd`. However, this is easily shown not to be regular using the pumping lemma or Myhill-Nerode theorem. This is a contradiction, so `L` must not be regular.